# Is it possible to create an RPM package from an install script?

Tags: rpm, packaging, rpmbuild

I'd like to easily create RPM packages for some random projects that do not come bundled as RPM (or whose RPMs are severely outdated).

Take the [Pop OS GTK theme](https://github.com/pop-os/gtk-theme) as an example.

Installing the theme is just a matter of running this script:

```
wget https://github.com/pop-os/gtk-theme/archive/3.1.2.tar.gz
tar zxf gtk-theme-3.1.2.tar.gz
cd gtk-theme-3.1.2
make
sudo make install
```

Is there a tool that would just basically run this script in a chrooted environment, grab all the "installed" files, and bundle them as an RPM package?

Comment: checkinstall makes deb packages, I don't remember if it does rpms.

Comment: The "pop-gtk-theme" is available as an SRC-RPM for e.g. Fedora 29 : pop-gtk-theme-2.2.3.0-3.fc28.src.rpm . ... The 'src.rpm' includes the spec file `pop-gtk-theme.spec` : Edit  2.2.3.0 to `3.1.2` etc. etc.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for the tip, altough I'm a bit reluctant to use the same spec file for another major release. I'd be much more comfortable finding a utility that does the above! This would be useful to me for other packages as well.

Comment: The spec file is a reminder of the many packages required for the build : 94 packages, Fedora 29. ... Build scripts for RPM ( Google, rpm build tool ) : This thread suggests SCons, Togo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040087/what-is-a-good-rpm-building-tool

Comment: You can use this wizard https://xsuchy.github.io/rpm-spec-wizard/ which will guide you step by step to create the SPEC file.